# Migrate AD DHCP

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp, windows-server-2016

Soon, I will need to migrate my domain controller server with AD DHCP 2012 R2 from a PowerEdge R430 to a virtual machine on Windows server 2016 based on VMware vSphere 6. 
Can anybody post a step-by-step procedure or indicate if there will be any downtime and if yes how long? 
Another question is about what I need to be very careful during the migration, I know ADMT to migrate Active Directory server but is there any tools to migrate   DHCP 
Thanks

Comment: You don't need ADMT if you are just adding a new domain controller to an existing domain. ADMT is for moving objects between domains. Will you be changing domains as part of the upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I appreciate these offerings may be a little tangential, you may find reviewing this Microsoft article useful.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn338978(v=ws.11).aspx

...specifically the DHCP failover option as a means of pushing DHCP config to a second server.

I had recent success using the Migration Tools feature to move DHCP from 2003 to 2012. You may wish to investigate that, though I cannot see a guide for the 12 > 16 scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Concerning the migration of DHCP the following steps may help you.

The prerequisites are that your server is already joined in the domain.

Downtime planned around a few minutes.

You should do it in a few steps like this:

1) Installing the DHCP Role

To install the DHCP server role, you must log on to the virtual machine with the Domain Administrator account.

Then click the Manage button in the Server Manager program and select Add roles or features

Then click the Next button on the introduction screen of the Roles and Features Installation Wizard in the new window that opened.

You must select the radio-button named Role-based or feature-based installation and click the Next button

After that, you must select the server on which you want to install the role and click on the Next button.

Then check the box labeled DHCP Server.

Then, click the Add Features button on the DHCP Server role management tools selection screen.

After that, click on the Next button to confirm the choices made.

Then click the Next button on the screen to select the features to install.

Then, click the Next button on the DHCP server role information screen.

Finally, click on the Install button on the summary screen of the chosen options to start the installation of the role.

2) Exporting parameters from the old DHCP server

After this, you must log in using the domain administrator's credentials on the old server.

Then, you must log on to PowerShell by pressing the Windows and R keys simultaneously, then enter powershell and press the Enter key.

Then, enter the following command in the window that opened:

`Netsh backup`

Then, enter the following command:

`Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Migration`

After that, enter the following command:

`Ipconfig / all> IPSettings.txt`

You must then enter the following command:

`Export-SmigServerSetting -featureID DHCP -User All -Group -IPConfig -path <storepath> -Verbose`

3) Importing Parameters to the New Server

After this, you must log in using the domain administrator credentials on the new server.

Then, you must log on to PowerShell by pressing the Windows and R keys simultaneously, then enter powershell and press the Enter key.

Then, enter the following command in the window that opened:

`Import-SmigServerSetting -featureid DHCP -User All -Group -IPConfig All -Force -path <storepath> -Verbose`

4) Stopping the DHCP service on the old server

After this, you must log in using the domain administrator's credentials on the old server.

Then, you must log on to PowerShell by pressing the Windows and R keys simultaneously, then enter powershell and press the Enter key.

Then, enter the following command in the window that opened:

`Stop-Service DHCPServer`

5) Starting the DHCP Service on the New Server

After this, you must log in using the domain administrator credentials on the new server.

Then, you must log on to PowerShell by pressing the Windows and R keys simultaneously, then enter Powershell and press Enter. 
Then, enter the following command in the window that opened:

`Start-Service DHCPServer`

6) Authorization of the new DHCP server

After this operation, it is necessary to connect using the identifiers of the domain administrator on The new server.

Then, you must log on to PowerShell by pressing the Windows and R keys simultaneously, then enter `powershell` and press the Enter key.

Then, enter the following command in the window that opened: 
`netsh DHCP add server FULLFQDN IP`

7) Removing the role of the old physical server

After this operation, You must log on using the domain administrator credentials on the old server. 
Then, you must log on to PowerShell by pressing the Windows and R keys simultaneously, then enter `powershell` and press the Enter key.

Then, you must enter the following command in the window that opened:

`Uninstall-WindowsFeature DHCPServer -Remove`

Following this, you must press the A key at the "Do you want to continue with this operation?

After the uninstallation, the server will restart.

8) Disconnecting the old physical server
You should power off and disconnect the old server and wait if there's any issues.

References:

Knowledge from my VAT in IT (CFC)

http://www.rebeladmin.com/2016/10/step-step-guide-migrate-active-directory-fsmo-roles-windows-server-2012-r2-windows-server-2016/

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772372.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just spin up the Server 2016 VM and add it as a DC in your domain with all the same roles, then ensure DHCP/AD/etc replication and shut down the 2012R2 physical.